# Kafka - Does local state store consumes application memory(JVM)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a consumer API thread running in my application(running on different node), my goal is to consume the incoming record from Kafka which will have unique id as key. Looking for an option to store the record processed by Kafka Consumer API so that my order can use it for display.

Planning to use Stream API to process and create a Ktable on Kafka broker. If I choose to use the persistent state store, does it still consumes my local application memory? If so, is it like temporarily and releases memory as soon as record is processed? Trying to avoid any memory issues within the application and see which state store option would best suits my use case. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> If I choose to use the persistent state store, does it still consumes my local application memory?

It depends on the underlying storage, it can be: a RocksDB, an in-memory hash map, or other data structure.

> If so, is it like temporarily and releases memory as soon as record is processed?

No

By the way: You should not deploy your Kafka Streams app on any Kafka broker.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes Kafka stream app will be sitting on consumer application not on Kafka broker.

Answer (score 0):

> create a Ktable on Kafka broker

A `KTable` will be populated client side.

> If I choose to use the persistent state store, does it still consumes my local application memory?

Even RocksDB would use some local memory obviously (note that memory would be off-heap as RocksDB is a C++ application that is integrated into the JVM via JNI). Or course, you can fine-tune/configure RocksDB to your needs and limit it's memory consumption accordingly. In general, RocksDB spills to disk and thus you can hold state that is larger than main-memory.

> Is it like temporarily and releases memory as soon as record is processed?

No. If you read a topic as a changelog, each record will be either an insert/update/delete (delete via tombstone, ie, value=`null`). Given that each record has unique ID, all records would be inserts and your KTable would grow unbounded.

How do you define "processed" for a record? If you can determine when a record is fully processed, you could use a `KafkaProducer` to write a tombstone into table input topic. KafkaStreams would eventually read and process this tombstone and delete the message from the KTable. It would be of course an async delete, but it might just work fine.